# Migrate TFS 2010 Application Tier to another server on the same domain

Tags: team-foundation-server, migration

I'm in the process of looking into the possibility of moving our TFS 2010 Application Tier to another server from the one it is on at the moment so that we can repurpose the hardware.

I've been looking through the Microsoft Documentation over at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx, but this assumes that everything is stored on one box (Application and Data tiers). In my setup however, our Data tier is separate to the Application tier and will be staying where it is.

I think I should be able to do this but for my own peace of mind, would there be any issues or implications if I merely installed the Application Tier on the new hardware and then connected it to the existing data tier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect to treat this as [Add An Application tier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578629.aspx).

It seems that there is no way to remove an app tier machine but this [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/tfsgeneral/thread/0ba7caad-4210-4991-b6f0-d4f1dd8c409b) (just tick the "not connected for 3 days" filter) implies a non-functional app tier is benign.

EDIT: This [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/1f36462e-f059-4b5c-b1fb-07be916c0fec) confirms this.